# Unicorn RainbowCodeGeneration is not supporting Sitecore 10.2 for serializing model

Tags: upgrade, unicorn

We are upgrading from `Sitecore 9.2` to `Sitecore 10.2`, earlier we used `Unicorn` and `RainbowCodeGeneration`, which used to work fine. During upgrade to `Sitecore 10.2`, we upgraded the `Sitecore.Kernal` version and below dlls

- **Sitecore.Kernel – 10.2**
- **RainbowCodeGeneration - 0.3.0**
- **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions - 3.1.14**
- **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection - 3.1.14**
- **Rainbow.Core - 2.1.4**
- **Rainbow.Storage.Yaml - 2.1.4**
- **RainbowCodeGeneration - 0.3.0**

So now when we are trying to generate code using `.tt` file, it throws error(PFA):

`Failing at:RainbowCodeGeneration.RainbowReader.GetTemplates(Host.ResolvePath(physicalFileStore), treeName, treePath); Attaching .tt file for the reference.`

It seems that the version RainbowCodeGenaration refers is not supported by `Sitecore.Kernal(10.2)`. So there seems an ambiguity between these versions.

`Exception: Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

So I want to know which version of `Rainbow` assemblies can support similar code generation feature with `Sitecore 10.2` as I am getting exceptions

I could see a similar issue was raised for `Sitecore 9.x` but there is nothing mentioned about `Sitecore 10.2`

Should I open a ticket to git repository developer.

Comment: Yea, you need to take this to the author of RainbowCodeGeneration. https://github.com/heikof/RainbowCodeGeneration

Comment: I still feel my question is valid and should be kept open for discussion as many Sitecore developers may encounter this issue in near future, but long story short, I got an alternate to fix this issue that is to use Sitecore CLI with leprechaun, this combination helped me to re-generate similar model classes now. Please find below link for idea.
https://gerhartmagdas.wordpress.com/2021/05/17/leprechaun-glassmapper-model-generation-with-sitecore-content-serialized-items/
Since question has been blocked now, so I have limit to share details about it now.